# Add image tags to native WordPress XML Sitemaps

Tags: seo, sitemap, google-xml-sitemaps

I would like to add image tags into my sitemap posts:

```
<image:image>
<image:loc>
<![CDATA[ https://example.com/image.jpg ]]>
</image:loc>
<image:caption>
<![CDATA[ Image caption  ]]>
</image:caption>
<image:title>
<![CDATA[ Image Title ]]>
</image:title>
</image:image>
```

Is there any filter that allows to add these tags into a native WP sitemap?

Thank you

Comment: In the [Make WP Core blogpost about adding sitemaps](https://make.wordpress.org/core/2020/07/22/new-xml-sitemaps-functionality-in-wordpress-5-5/) this is discussed under "Adding Additional Tags to Sitemap Entries" - have you tried any of these filters already?

Comment: I have edited my answer because I realized that the 'wp_sitemaps_posts_entry' filter ony allows to edit loc and lastmod: Fields other than %s are not currently supported for the sitemap index

Comment: So it is not possible with the methods described there?

Comment: I have not been able to achieve it. I found the message above in class-wp-sitemaps-renderer.php. These are the allowed fields: 'loc', 'lastmod', 'changefreq', 'priority'.

Comment: @Pbinder did you ever find a work-around for this using WP core?

Answer (score 0):

I did it in my website: https://canelaza.com/post-sitemap.xml

[image]

with custom code in wordpress-seo and functions.php

**Functions.php**

```
function filter_wpseo_sitemap_entry( $url, $p, $post ){
    global $wpdb;
    $upload_dir   = wp_upload_dir();
    if(isset($url['images']) && is_array($url['images']) && count($url['images'])){
        foreach($url['images'] as &$img){
            if(!$img['title']){
                $sql = "SELECT post_id FROM ".$wpdb->prefix.'postmeta WHERE meta_key="_wp_attached_file" AND meta_value="'.str_replace($upload_dir['baseurl'].'/', '', $img['src']).'"';
                $thumb_id = $wpdb->get_var($sql);
                if($title = get_the_title($thumb_id)){
                    $img['title'] = $title;    
                }
                if($excerpt = get_the_excerpt($thumb_id)){
                    $img['caption'] = $excerpt;    
                }
            }
        }
    }
    if(!isset($url['images'][0]['title'])){
        $url['images'][0]['title'] = $post->post_title;
    }
    return $url;
}
add_filter( 'wpseo_sitemap_entry', 'filter_wpseo_sitemap_entry', 10, 3 );
```

**wordpress-seo/inc/sitemaps/class-sitemaps-renderer.php - function sitemap_url**

```
public function sitemap_url( $url ) {

        $date = null;

        if ( ! empty( $url['mod'] ) ) {
            // Create a DateTime object date in the correct timezone.
            $date = YoastSEO()->helpers->date->format( $url['mod'] );
        }

        $output  = "\t<url>\n";
        $output .= "\t\t<loc>" . $this->encode_and_escape( $url['loc'] ) . "</loc>\n";
        $output .= empty( $date ) ? '' : "\t\t<lastmod>" . htmlspecialchars( $date, ENT_COMPAT, $this->output_charset, false ) . "</lastmod>\n";

        if ( empty( $url['images'] ) ) {
            $url['images'] = [];
        }

        foreach ( $url['images'] as $img ) {

            if ( empty( $img['src'] ) ) {
                continue;
            }

            $output .= "\t\t<image:image>\n";
            $output .= "\t\t\t<image:loc>" . $this->encode_and_escape( $img['src'] ) . "</image:loc>\n";
            if(isset($img['caption']) && $img['caption'] && strlen($img['caption']) > 2){
                $output .= "\t\t\t<image:caption><![CDATA[" . $img['caption']  . "]]></image:caption>\n";
            }
            if(isset($img['title']) && $img['title'] && strlen($img['title']) > 2){
                $output .= "\t\t\t<image:title><![CDATA[" . $img['title']  . "]]></image:title>\n";
            }
            $output .= "\t\t</image:image>\n";
        }
        unset( $img );

        $output .= "\t</url>\n";

        /**
         * Filters the output for the sitemap URL tag.
         *
         * @api   string $output The output for the sitemap url tag.
         *
         * @param array $url The sitemap URL array on which the output is based.
         */
        return apply_filters( 'wpseo_sitemap_url', $output, $url );
    }
```

Comment: It looks good but I don't use wordpress-seo. Thanks